Pip not functioning properly
I am encountering an error with  my pip whenever I am trying to run a command with pip or any pip-related command it gives me the same mistake over and over again
So whenever  i try a pip command it gives me a error and its the same eroor no matter what command i use.I tried checking the version of it  then it gives me some er ror with python 311. i have tried updating it reinstalling pip but nothing works.
i have aslo shared the snips of the errors.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Have you tried reinstalling Python altogether?

You seem to have an old pip version incompatible with Python 3.10+. Try to get a newer version by one of the methods in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/ .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As I see, you're using Windows as OS, you must need to add PIP to PATH, make sure you add it, try to reinstall the GUI version of python and check the add to PATH
Check this out this guide
Also, the right command is
$ pip -V


I tried what you asked me to do but the thing is that I am trying to reinstall pip but it isn't allowing me to download pip due to the same error which previously occurred,therefore it's getting difficult for me to add it again to the environment variables
